# Whiptail mixing SUDO and regular user commands

Tags: bash

I am writing an install script that requires a wget and install to /usr/bin followed by some commands that need to be run as the main user.

I can use the whiptail to get the password:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
PWD=""

checkPermissions() {
  #Password Input
  PSW=$(whiptail --title "Sudo Required" --passwordbox "Enter your sudo password and choose Ok to continue." 10 60 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3)
  exitstatus=$?
  if [ $exitstatus = 0 ]; then
    #sudo -S <<< $PSW script.sh
    return
  else
    whiptail --title "Cancel" --msgbox "This script requires sudo permissions to install some programs." 10 60
    exit 1
  fi
}

sudo -u root -S <<< $PSW mkdir /usr/local/share/myprog
sudo -u $SUDO_USER mkdir /home/$SUDO_USER/myprog
```

But bash says "sudo not found". What is the correct way to mix user commands in a script?

Comment: what kind of OS are you running the script on? Can you run `type -a sudo` from your main interactive shell?

Comment: If sudo is not found, it's not in the PATH -- either because the correct directory is missing from PATH or because sudo isn't installed.